# Convert Query from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello guys someone can help me converting this query to work on Oracle ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
CAST(DATEADD(DAY,CONVERT(INT, 
Convert(nvarchar(50),(ASCII(SUBSTRING(A1_USERLGI,12,1)) - 50))+Convert(nvarchar(50),(ASCII(SUBSTRING(A1_USERLGI,16,1)) - 50))), 
'1996-01-01') AS DATETIME),103) FROM SA1010 where A1_USERLGI <> ' ';
```

This code for decoding a econded field that's save user from system cod and the date of change.

Comment: Do you have any data ? Like, from this data I expect to get this data ?

Comment: @JohnnyCamargo . .  Please explain what the code does.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hello this code convert a encoded field that's store user code from system and date like when doing any change or inserting something this field for log but this store encoded so this code return the field decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just with a few changes the Sql can be put in the Oracle flavor.

CONVERT of the date to string becomes TO_CHAR.
SUBSTRING becomes SUBSTR.
`+` becomes `||` or CONCAT.
DATEADD of n days to a date becomes date + n
ASCII remains ASCII.
CAST works for both.

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR((CAST('01-JAN-1996' AS DATE) + 
CAST(CONCAT((ASCII(SUBSTR(A1_USERLGI, 12, 1))-50), 
(ASCII(SUBSTR(A1_USERLGI, 16, 1))-50)) AS NUMBER)), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS dt
FROM SA1010 where A1_USERLGI <> ' ';
```